# Assign intervals / bins by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, intervals

I would like to apply a function by group that assigns the interval that an observation belongs to based on the values in that group to a new variable. I feel like the following code should work, but it seems to be using the entire dataset as opposed to the max and min for the group. What am I missing?

```
#require(data.table)
#fake data
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- data.frame(id_f=c(rep("a a",100),rep("b b",100),rep("c c",100)), 
                   L=c(abs(rnorm(100,50,20)),abs(rnorm(100,90,20)),abs(rnorm(100,220,20))), 
                   w=abs(rnorm(300,6,3))) 
dt2 = as.data.table(df1)

#the offending data.table function
dt2[,"bins":= findInterval(L, c((max(L)-min(L))/10*c(1:9)),left.open=T)+1, by=id_f]
```

EDIT:

In column "a a" there would 10 equally spaced bins across the range of "a a", and a bin-number would be assigned to each of the original observations, as the real data has 6,000 observations there are multiple members in each bin. So the output would be something like: (for the sake of brevity this is a three-interval example)

```
id_f  L    w     bins
a a   1    1.0   1
a a   2    1.1   2
a a   3    5.0   3
b b   3    2.0   1
b b   6    3.5   2
b b   9    7.0   3
c c   10   1.0   1
c c   15   1.5   2
c c   20   6.0   3
```

I would have thought that my invocation of `findInterval` would accomplish this, but clearly it is taking `min` and `max` from the global dataset and not from just the group. How do I get it to grab `min` and `max` from the group and then use that to calculate the interval to use for that group?

Comment: `cut()` is the builtin that does this, pass it an explicit `breaks` argument. Also please use `set.seed()` when you use random data, to make this reproducible for the rest of us. After multiple edits this question is still not reproducible, argh.

Comment: will set.seed in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `cut` would be much easier here by specifying number of `breaks` we want

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt2)[,"bins":= cut(L, breaks = 10, labels = 1:10), by=id_f]

dt2
#     id_f     L     w bins
#  1:  a a  71.5  2.96    8
#  2:  a a  49.5  3.63    5
#  3:  a a  49.3  6.90    5
#  4:  a a  19.7 10.92    2
#  5:  a a  65.8  9.25    7
# ---                      
#296:  c c 206.0  6.50    4
#297:  c c 224.8  4.04    6
#298:  c c 213.0 10.36    5
#299:  c c 227.4  3.58    6
#300:  c c 224.9  7.12    6
```

---

We can do this in `dplyr` or base R as well

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 %>%
  group_by(id_f) %>%
  mutate(bins = cut(L, breaks = 10, labels = 1:10))
```

OR

```
with(dt2, ave(L, id_f, FUN = function(x) cut(x, breaks = 10, labels = 1:10)))
```

Comment: Yes! cut is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run tabular functions to demonstrate the issue. The `by`-operation seems to be "working"

```
    > dt2[ , list(mn=min(L), mx=max(L) ), by=id_f]
   id_f         mn       mx
1:  a a   5.462025 104.2456
2:  b b  43.824476 138.4843
3:  c c 168.075002 276.5598
> dt2[ , table(id_f, bins)]
     bins
id_f    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  a a   3   5  10  10  19  13  21  10   4   5
  b b   0   0   0   0   1   3  10   8  19  59
  c c   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 100
```

Obviously your results will vary since you didn't use `set.seed()`

```
png(); par(mfrow=c(3,1)); tapply(df1$L, df1$id_f, hist); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code generating the data is working exactly as it should. The issue, I think, is that min() and max() are coming from the global data.table and not the subset indicated by the grouping variable in "by=id_f". See edited question.